# How is 'Function' (not 'function') defined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I happened to notice Javascript also supports the `Function` keyword just as in ActionScript. Since both are derived from ECMA Script, existence of such similarities is a common knowledge. But I was curious on what **Function** represents in case of Javascript, if not a Class(as in as3).

In JS,

`var func = new Function();`  or  `var func = new Function;`

Assigns a function called 'anonymous' to the variable 'func'.

Could it be simply a method to implement the actual 'function' in an Object oriented way..

Since most browsers(ff, ie & chrome) seem to implement it in the same way, is it addressed in the spec?

Comment: Check this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: `Function` isn't really a keyword. It's just an identifier used as the name of an object constructor. Functions are objects, but there's different syntax allowed for creating them.

Comment: Here: http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is the "class" all function extend from.  All functions are really `Function` objects.

```
(function(){}) instanceof Function === true
```

You can also use `new Function` to make a function from a string (like `eval`).

```
var func = new Function('x,y', 'return x+y;')
```

Comment: You forgot some quotation marks in your last example. They need to be separate string arguments to the constructor instead of a comma-separated string.

Comment: @thesystem: They can be either/or :-)  See the note at http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.2.1

Comment: Really? My apologies. I never knew that.

Comment: @thesystem: Nope. A comma-separated string is also allowed. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and the note to http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.2.1.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Well, whatever happened to the 'no classes' behavior of JS... thanks :)

Comment: @loxxy: That's why I put `class` in quotes.  It's not really a class, but I didn't want to confuse you :-)

Answer (score 2):

"Every function in JavaScript is actually a Function object." [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

```
function myFunc(a, b) {
  console.log( 'test' );
}
```

is essentially equal to

```
var myFunc = new Function('a', 'b', 'console.log( "test" )');
```

There are however some differences between to two ways of declaring a function. Read the doc!

Comment: They're very similar, but there are some important differences. One is that the first syntax will be "hoisted". But more importantly, the second syntax will be evaluated in the global variable scope instead of the local one. JS interpreters don't use constructor functions internally.

Comment: Thanks @the system, just clarified this by re-reading the relevant docs. Edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

1 way:

```
var Person = function() {
    this.name;
    this.age;
}

var p1 = new Person();
```

2nd way:

```
function Person() {
    this.name;
    this.age;
}

var p1 = new Person();
```

Comment: This is about function expressions and function declarations, not about the Function constructor.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking.